# EOMONTH function in Microsoft SQL did not return records in December 31

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was doing a question that required me to show all orders made on the last day of the
month and order by `EmployeeID` and `OrderID`. When I used `EOMONTH`, the result did not include records on December 31, 2015. Would be glad if someone can help me point out the problem here.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, OrderID, OrderDate 
FROM Northwind.dbo.Orders
WHERE OrderDate = EOMONTH(OrderDate)
```

The two missing records were:

```
    EmployeeID      OrderID            OrderDate
    3                10806             2015-12-31 11:00:00.000
    4                10807             2015-12-31 11:00:00.000
```

Here is the link to the SQL file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMo8DMqHrhV67gqkyERA_YsWbIhZxjrk/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the documentation for EOMONTH **again**. What is the datatype of the return value. Or simply run the query `select EOMONTH('20151231 11:00')`. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: where convert(date, OrderDate) = EOMONTH(OrderDate)

Comment: EOMONTH returns the last day of the month _at midnight_. You need to change your where clause, e.g. `WHERE OrderDate >= EOMONTH(OrderDate)`. You can convert the source to date but this is counter-intuitive as in all other cases that kills sargability (and even in this case brings other issues). See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047

Answer (score 0):

EOMonth returns date value and in the where clause the condition is between datetime vs date. So modify the query as below.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, OrderID, OrderDate 
FROM Northwind.dbo.Orders
WHERE cast(OrderDate as date)= EOMONTH(OrderDate)
```

Comment: But because of https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047 and because in all other cases applying calculations against the column will prevent a seek, I’d much rather do `WHERE OrderDate >= EOMONTH(OrderDate)`.